# How to get response status in Retrofit (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am using Retrofit. Using Kotlin. I need to know the resonse status code. Like is it 200  or 500. How can I get it from the response ?

My Api class:

```
interface Api {
    @POST("user/code/check")
    fun checkSmsCode(@Body body: CheckCodeBody): Single<Response<Void>> }
```

This is how I am calling Api. But note that SERVE DOES NOT RETURN CODE FIELD IN RESPONSE BODY!

```
api.checkSmsCode(
   CheckCodeBody(
       code = code
   )
)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe({         
      //HOW TO CHECK STATUS RESPONSE STATUS CODE HERE???
    }, 
    { e ->
        when (e) {
            is IOException -> view?.showNoNetworkAlert()
            else -> view?.invalidCodeError()
        }
     }
).also {}
```

As I understood, in Java it was a easy peasy thing.

You just use `response.code()` or something similar and that's it. But how to achieve it in Kotlin?

Comment: `But how to achieve it in Kotlin?` Retrofit is a Java library, and Kotlin interops with Java; so you need to do the exact same thing you would do in Java.

Comment: Well it is not that easy as it seems. You cannot access this stuff from Kotlin as it turns out. I have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: You can probably access it using ```it``` word, ```it.code()``` to be exact.

Comment: @r2rek it is not working.

Comment: How do you define `checkSmsCode`?

Comment: cant you just use response.code() in the response?

Comment: There is no `code` coming from the server.

Comment: I mean in the response body. Java did not require to have the code in the response body if I am not mistaken.

Comment: please paste your api interface code.

Comment: @r2rek edited the question. Please have a look!

Comment: wait so you are not even getting a response at all is that what you mean?

Comment: Always prefer to name a single-arg parameter of a lambda if the lambda is multi-line, instead of calling it `it`. Names are useful.

Answer (score 0):

so your on response should look something like this

```
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyModel>?, response: Response<MyModel>?) {
           //
      }
 })
```

then inside that you should just to able to do

```
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyModel>?, response: Response<MyModel>?) {
           response.code()
      }
 })
```

is this what your talking about?

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't configure your retrofit request method to return a `Response<*>` you won't be able to have the response code. Example:

```
interface SomeApi{
 @POST("user/code/check")
fun checkSmsCode(@Body body: CheckCodeBody): Single<Response<String>> 
}
```

And after you finish your request:

```
.subscribe({
 //access response code here like : it.code()
 //and you can access the response.body() for your data
 //also you can ask if that response.isSuccessful
})
```

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look sir!.

Comment: Replace `Single<BaseResult<String>>` with `Single<Response<String>>`. Don't worry about the result like that. Retrofit handles it for you.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Did not help. : (

Answer (score 0):

yo need to use it

```
interface OnlineStoreService{

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json","Connection: close")
    @POST
    fun getDevices(
            @Url url: String,
            @Header("Authorization") token: String,
            @Body apiParams: APIParams
    ): Observable<OnlineStoresInfo>

} 


.subscribe({ onlineStoresInfo ->   // or it -> where "it" it's your object response, in this case is my class OnlineStoresInfo

                    loading.value = false
                    devices.value = onlineStoresInfo.devices

                }, { throwable ->
                    Log.e(this.javaClass.simpleName, "Error getDevices ", throwable)
                    loading.value = false
                    error.value = context.getString(R.string.error_information_default_html)
                })

.subscribe({ it -> 
// code
}, { throwable ->
 //code
})
```